# Centering one Table inside another

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following table. I would like centering the table on the top to avoid blank space after column 6. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]\caption{Titre} \centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\resizebox{17cm}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\toprule
\cmidrule(r){2-2}   \cmidrule(r){3-7}              
&     (1)     &    (2)    &     (3)      &   (4)    &   (5)    &   (6)          \\
& A & B & C & D  &  E &  F     \\
\cmidrule(r){2-2}   \cmidrule(r){3-7} 
Variable  &  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
\cmidrule(r){2-2}   \cmidrule(r){3-7}   
& \\                    
&     (7)     &    (8)    &     (9)      &   (10)    &   (11)    &   (12)      & (13)    \\
& E & F&  G & K  & L &  M & N  \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-2}  \cmidrule(r){3-3} \cmidrule(r){4-6} \cmidrule(r){7-8}
Variable & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\cmidrule(r){2-2}  \cmidrule(r){3-3} \cmidrule(r){4-6} \cmidrule(r){7-8}  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why are you using that `\makebox\resizebox` combination?

Comment: Is splitting of your table into two tables, first with 7 and second with 8 columns and than both centered in `table` environment acceptable option? Why you resize table? As it is, it can be fit in text width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, you need to provide two separate `tabular` environments if you want to center them horizontally with regard to each other. And, by all means, get rid of the `\resizebox` and `\makebox` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]\caption{Titre} 
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} l*{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule             
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
& A & B & C & D & E & F     \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}   \cmidrule(l){3-7} 
Variable  &  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip % or: \bigskip, ...
\begin{tabular}{@{} l*{7}{c} @{}}  
\toprule  
& (07) & (08) & (09) & (10) & (11) & (12) & (13) \\
& E & F & G & K & L & M & N  \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}  \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
Variable & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi approach is also two separate tabular, but making them look just like one, with  1-6 and 7-13 columns of the same width, that seem closer that you tried. As the question is tagged with `tabularx` for some reason, this approach use it, but with fewer horizontal lines.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]\caption{Titre} 
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.8\linewidth}{m{4em}YYYYYY}\toprule 
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
 & A & B & C & D & E & F \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-7} 
Variable & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\\%\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{.8\linewidth}{m{4em}YYYYYYY} 
& (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) & (11) & (12) & (13) \\
& E & F& G & K & L & M & N \\ 
\cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-6} \cmidrule(rl){7-8}
Variable & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```